# jQuery change input value inside dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I have dynamic table that is created via script:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    if (newcell.childNodes[0].className === 'ui-widget ui-autocomplete-input') {
                        $(newcell.childNodes).autocomplete({
                            source: 'sites/produkt_suche.php'
                        });
                    }
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value= "";
                    break;
            case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
        }
        $(".ui-widget").focusout(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "sites/produkt_preis.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { text: text },
                success: function(result){
                    $("td:first-child").next().next().next().find("input").val($(this).innerHTML = result);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({url: "sites/produkt_beschreibung.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { text: text },
                success: function(result){
                    newcell.lastChild.value = result;
                }
            });
        });
    }

}
```

I need to fill the last input inside the last td with a value I get via ajax and I also need to fill the second to last input inside the second to last td with an other value I get via ajax.

Currenty it is partially working even though not very good.
The last input gets filled correctly, but it's done for all rows underneath as well (only last input).

The second to last input gets filled correctly, but it's done for all rows underneath and above (only second to last input)

Can you guys help me out? As you can see I am new to javascript and jQuery.

Comment: I think you need to ask a broader question if you want people to help. The provided code is hard to read and isn't efficient (making 3 different ajax requests for the same table, deep nesting etc.). Long story short: What is it exactly what you want to do? Do you want to render a table using AJAX?

Comment: I create a one row table via standard html. With a button I want to add a row to the table having the same <td> as the first one. (This works flawless). In every <td> I have a textbox. The first textbox uses autocomplete from jQuery. Depending on what I choose from the autocomplete the second to last textbox get's filled with the returned value from the first $.ajax (it's opening a php file which gets the data from a database). The last textbox get's filled with the 2nd $.ajax (basically the same, but a different php file). This filling doesn't work as intended as written in the question.

Comment: @JasonK forgot to include your name